# Pubnub message decrypt issue using pubnub.decrypt method

Tags: reactjs, pubnub

I'm facing issue with older messages only which are published long ago so i felt that it was encrypted with using another symmetric key,
but now when i was trying to decrypt those messages using same key it won't work

We are publishing message like below

[image]

And while receving we are decrypting our messages like below

[image]

But it will always return null data, not able to decrypt.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where you are using a cipher key to encrypt the messages. Can you show where you use cipher key to encrypt the messages?

Comment: return pubnub.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), SYMMETRIC_KEY); like this we are using

Comment: I can only assume the cipher key that encrypted the data is not same as cipher key that is decrypting the data. You say messages were published long ago, but you did not say if those old messages were encrypted or not or if the cipher key might have changed. Or possibly older PN SDK vs newer SDK where encrypt is not backward compatible (unlikely but need to verify). Could any of that be the issue.

Comment: @CraigConover Yes older messages are encrypted only, and it was working fine in prodcution which was deployed long ago, but now locally it won't working,
And if i will send any new message it was working

Comment: @VishalNai I assume, production code runs on version which is older than v4.31.0 and locally you use v4.31.0 and above, right?

Comment: @VishalNai newer version of SDK won't understand encrypted messages from older one because of breaking change at v4.31.0. You can keep it backward compatible by setting `useRandomIVs` to `false`.

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov  Thanks for solutions, actually i was using same version in local and prod which are 4.27.3 still getting that issue, but when i have add useRandomIVs: false it's working, i'm wondering how it should any guess?,

And also which steps i need to follow while upgrading version?

Comment: @VishalNai `useRandomIVs` appeared since *v4.31.0*. Are you sure, that locally never version not installed (maybe `package.json` wasn't too restrictive and actual version can be found in `package-lock.json` should tell really version).

Comment: Yes in both package and package.lock json file versions are older and also i have verified in node_modules also, but when i tried useRandomIVs it was working so is there any update from pubnub side which i might be missing or anything else?

Comment: @VishalNai checked code, `useRandomIVs` added since **4.29.0**. `useRandomIVs` affects only client instance behaviour (because *encryption* / *decryption* happens on client side), not related to anything what happens on PubNub service.